# My Sharepoint styled header text is breaking words in order to wrap lines. How can I prevent this?

Tags: html, css, text

I would like the text to break only on whitespace, as is normally expected. Here is the css that Sharepoint generated for the line:

`<span class="Apple-style-span" style="color:rgb(0, 114, 188);font-size:26px;line-height:39px"></span>`

Comment: Look through the entire css for `word-break` and `word-wrap`.

Comment: @MarcB Are those the only two css attributes that will cause this? They are nowhere to be found.

Comment: Gahh I found it. MS is good at hiding their Sharepoint styles. Add that as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `word-wrap` and `word-break` styles were set correctly. I ended up fixing the issue by changing the `<span>` tag to a `<p>`.

Answer (score 1):

Look through the entire css for `word-break` and `word-wrap`